# Spring Cloud Stream consumer startup

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I recently migrated my spring cloud stream  kafka consumer application from annotations to a functional approach  and now it won't start up with the failure

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:403)\n\t... 33 common frames omitted\nCaused by: 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, 
but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information 
from the user
\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:172)
\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)
\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:73)
\n\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)\n
\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:474)\n\
t... 40 common frames omitted\nCaused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
```

This is the configuration  :

```
jaas:
  options:
    sauAlias: Vault/Conjur/Secret/service_account
    useKeyTab: false
    krbProvider: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
    debug: true
  loginModule: com.usaa.kafka.auth3.krb.SauKrbLoginModuleWrapper
  bootstrapServers: >
    someserver:0000, someserver:0001
```

Is there an attribute that needs to be set to avoid the login prompt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, you will see that for Krb5LoginModule if use:

```
useKeyTab:
    Set this to true if you want the module to get the principal's key from the the keytab.(default value is False) If keytab is not set then the module will locate the keytab from the Kerberos configuration file. If it is not specified in the Kerberos configuration file then it will look for the file {user.home}{file.separator}krb5.keytab.
```

In your case, my assumption is that because you are using `useKeyTab = false`, it is trying to find the keytab file in the default location:  `{user.home}{file.separator}krb5.keytab.` and it probably does not exist.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html

---

Please see this https://andriymz.github.io/kerberos/authentication-using-kerberos/#krb5loginmodule for possible Valid/Invalid configuration combinations.

---

Your Configuration should look something like:

```
spring:
 cloud:
  stream:
   kafka:
    binder:
     brokers: localhost:9092  # path to kafka brokers
     autoCreateTopics: false
     jaas:
      loginModule: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
      controlFlag: required
      options: 
       useKeyTab: true
       storeKey: true
       keyTab: /your/pathTokeytabFile
       useTicketCache: false
       principal: yourserviceaccount@domain
       renewTicket: true
       serviceName: kafka
     configuration: 
       security:
         protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
       sasl: 
         kerberos: 
           service:
             name: kafka
     producerProperties:
       retries: 3
    bindings:
     CONSUMER_ONE:
      destination: TOPIC_1
      contentType: application/json
     CONSUMER_TWO:
      destination: TOPIC_2
      contentType: application/json
     CONSUMER_ERROR:
      destination: ERROR_TOPIC
      contentType: application/json
     PRODUCER_ONE:
      destination: TOPIC_2
      contentType: application/json
     PRODUCER_TWO:
      destination: TOPIC_3
      contentType: application/json
     PRODUCER_ERROR:
      destination: ERROR_TOPIC
      contentType: application/json
```

Comment: thanks for the input, links, and context! I will check my configuration and redeploy. If these suggestions lead to a successful startup I will accept the answer.

Comment: The problem was the I had:  `spring:   kafka:  jaas: `  instead of  `spring:  cloud:  stream:      kafka: binder: jaas: `